# Feed carbon/graphite from a remote host

Tags: graphite

I have installed graphite on a dedicated Ubuntu server and it correctly collects its own system performance data e.g. `cpu usage` and `load_avg` and send it to carbon then I can see those metric data on graphite web.

The issue now is that I want to send those metric data from multiple hosts to the carbon/graphite server.

I used [diamond](https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Diamond) to send data to the server holding graphite/carbon and it successfully created my naming scheme into graphite but I can't see those data on graphite-web.

Any additional requirements to feed these data into carbon and get it visualized into graphite-web?

Here is carbon already listening on port 2003 for all its interfaces

```
lnxg33k@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -nltp | grep python

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2003            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2114/python     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2004            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2114/python     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2114/python
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406789/where-are-my-logstash-metrics-in-graphite/20417377#20417377

Answer (score 3):

To test graphite-web/carbon configuration it is enough to use bash commands, e.g.:

```
echo "local.random.diceroll $(((RANDOM%6)+1)) `date +%s`" | nc localhost 2003;
```

(replace localhost with your graphite hostname if you're not running the command from the same server)

If you use whisper as a storage you should see some database files in your `GRAPHITE_STORAGE_DIR` dir, e.g.:

```
/opt/graphite/storage/whisper/
```

it could be configured in `$GRAPHITE_ROOT/conf/carbon.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I sent information from localhost, I could graph the output. However from a remote node the same commands didn't produce graphable-information.
I finally understood what was happening when I used "whisper-dump.py" on the whisper file. I could see my values, but the ones inserted from the local machine didn't appear close to the ones from my remote machine.

Of course the problem was that the 2 machines weren't synchronised with NTP.
Once they both had the correct time, everything worked perfectly.